# 'Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1, yajra-datatable

Hi guys I am trying to fix this about 1 week and I am stucked here. I try a lot of things like: composer-dumpload, clearing cache, capitalizing service provider like this:
**Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider**
I run multiple versions of Yajra like 5 and 6.

Here is my app.config

```
Providers
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
    Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class

Alias
    'Datatables' => Yajra\Datatables\Facades\Datatables::class,
```

So I don't know what more have to do. I have Laravel 5.1 version and must be this version and not a new one.

If we can help me with this I will be very happy.

Thanks

Comment: Did you run the `composer require yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle` command per the docs?

Comment: Did you run the `php artisan vendor:publish --provider=Yajra\DataTables\DataTablesServiceProvider` to publish it?

Comment: Also note the case in the name `Data Tables Service Provider`

Comment: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables seems to indicate it's `DataTables`, not `Datatables`, too. In a variety of spots.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes sir.

Comment: @AngadDubey Says the same error on command line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `yajra` (lowercase). So in providers you should have:

```
yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider
```

and for alias you should have

```
yajra\Datatables\Datatables::class
```

If you look at [official documentation](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables/tree/5.0#quick-installation) you will see it's lowercase

Comment: Thank you so much! You are the best men.

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a yajra dataTable related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208578/laravel-yajra-datatable-cannot-retrieve-the-search-parameter-from-ajax-call-in ?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Yajra instead of yajra. So in providers you should have

```
yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider
```

and for alias you should have

```
yajra\Datatables\Datatables::class
```